# Airflow: Next Run is not scheduled somehow

Tags: airflow

I don't know why but some of my DAGs are stuck even though I set them up as daily jobs. As you can see in this picture, last run time and next run time are exactly the same.

[image]

I compared DAG configurations of ones working and not working and I don't see any difference. What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Its schedule is set as "0 10 * * *"

Comment: Please provide your process definition.